# how to use quoting and escaping with bash

Tags: bash, curl

I was given a list of urls that are generating 404 errors as reported to us by google.

I can test a url with curl (from the command line )  like this:

```
curl -k --user-agent "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)" https://MYURLHERE
```

which works exactly as I expected. I wanted to put this in a script so I can run through a list of them 
here is what I have.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
url=$1

curlcmd="curl -k --user-agent \"Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)\""
$curlcmd $url
```

but its not working. I keep getting

```
curl: (1) Protocol "(+http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I'm not sure how to escape this to make it work. any suggestions ?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to add single quote inside of a bash variable?](https://serverfault.com/questions/875445/how-to-add-single-quote-inside-of-a-bash-variable) (and superuser: "[How do I use a Bash variable (string) containing quotes in a command?](https://superuser.com/questions/360966/how-do-i-use-a-bash-variable-string-containing-quotes-in-a-command)"). See also [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

put quotes around your variable $1, or you can use something like this:

```
$ touch $$
$ echo 'http://www.google.com' >> $$
$ echo 'http://www.yahoo.com' >> $$
$ for url in $(cat $$); do curl -I $url ; done
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:57:19 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2017-11-22-15; expires=Fri, 22-Dec-2017 15:57:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=117=CaOUCOyr9TPjs64tqyz1MuqHsASzL_3eO5n-NE4ubqAikITGbs7QY0aegNByOWX1Vaf9SsUVQDJ1wdaIOZwXoiqfVZ9ISLtta7tvcDH6LFM52OGFKRH4J5Clde2EX8oG; expires=Thu, 24-May-2018 15:57:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Age: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:57:19 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2017-11-22-15; expires=Fri, 22-Dec-2017 15:57:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=117=VRrA0-bCESlSCoerEK0n1hxXfldwpQI4cisiKrEgnKVph9HkfQJu-tbur3ZBiLh3-RFKZ0kbWUWsBwJKzsi_aPUuJzztM1rCuDfljZLxqjaHanZxiCx7qch4P2WCoDDC; expires=Thu, 24-May-2018 15:57:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Age: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Via: 1.1 localhost.localdomain

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Nov 2017 15:57:19 GMT
Via: http/1.1 media-router-fp56.prod.media.ne1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [c s f ]), 1.1 localhost.localdomain
Server: ATS
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, private
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Language: en
Expires: -1
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 12
Age: 0

$
```

Comment: I"m sorry i do not understand what you are telling me. I would like to run curl as a googlebot  and pull down a url passed to the script so i can see what googlebot sees when it tries to crawl this url

Comment: @GeneralFoch assuming your list of URLs inside of file, you can run against that list, or as I mentioned earlier you can put double quotes around your parameter, that should do the trick for you as well.

Comment: i placed the $url in double quotes, but still get the message `curl: (1) Protocol "(+http" not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Answer (score 0):

You may modify it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
url="$1"

curlcmd='curl -k --user-agent "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"'
$curlcmd "$url"
```

The message, you're getting, says that http (default) is not supported. Use https instead:

```
./test.sh https://www.somepage.com
```

Comment: I tried the the change above using single quotes for the curlcmd and then placing the $url inside double quotes.   the url i pass is https .  still get the same message as before.

note when i run directly from the command line, i do not get that message.

Comment: but you have to use https protocol (test.sh https://www.somepage.com)

Comment: test.sh getspassed  https://MYURLHERE     (  all passed urls are https)  

i may not understand what you are telling me but the only http  is in the curlcmd

Comment: It works for me fine. I get your message only in case I try to access https only page via http. Is there a chance, that you have to use proxy at your site?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem...I just get this nonsensical sounding warning, and otherwise it works:

```
curl: (3) URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535
```

And while the error is hard to understand, really this is the wrong way to do things. It's almost always a bad idea to execute things in variables without quotes. And simply adding quotes would fail:

```
url=https://startpage.com
curlcmd="curl -k --user-agent \"Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)\""
"$curlcmd" "$url"
```

With quotes wrongly used above, the error is this, because it made that whole cmd including all the spaces into one argumentless command:

```
bash: curl -k --user-agent "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)": No such file or directory
```

And the cause of your problem is probably the space between "2.1" and "(". With quotes, all the spaces are mangled into one large argument that doesn't make sense. Without, they are separate, but that space after "2.1" also splits it into another argument.

Also, you can use `eval` to make it actually logical for some escaping of that space to actually work ...but I don't recommend eval.

I like to use functions for this kind of thing. (this probably also works in sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
url="$1"

mycurl() {
    curl -k --user-agent "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "$@"
}

mycurl "$url"
```

or an array works too (but not in sh ...don't be fooled by systems where `sh` is just `bash --posix`)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
url="$1"

curlcmd=(curl -k --user-agent "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)")

# an example of the main reason I generally use an array... you can modify the command dynamically
if [ "$DEBUG" = 1 ]; then
    curlcmd+=(-v)
fi

# and this runs it... fully protected variables in quotes, but also easy, unlike all the other escaping methods
"${curlcmd[@]}" "$url"
```

Answer (score 0):

For querying a **list of URLs** given as command line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

USER_AGENT="Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"

curl_with_ua(){
  curl -k --user-agent "$USER_AGENT" "$1"
}

for url in "$@"; do
  curl_with_ua "$url"
done
```